# Issue with timing of SQL query firing in JPA

Tags: jpa, entitymanager

I am using JPA for data persistence.

I am unable to explain a behaviour in my program.

I have an entity `A` which has another entity `B` as its member.In my code I create new instance of `A` and set an instance of `B` (fetched from database) in `A`,and then I save `A` using `EntityManager`. I am using container managed transaction, hence all transactions are supposed to commit at end of the method.

In very same method, after persisting `A`, I try to fetch an entity of class `C`. `C`, like `A`, has `B` as its member. I use a JQPL query to fetch `C` for id of `B`'s instance I associated with `A`'s instance previously.

Issue is that while fetching `C`, JPA is also executing SQL query to save `A`. I expect that to happen at end of transaction (ie when method ends).
But its happening while I try to fetch `C`. If I don't fetch `C`, then SQL query for saving `A` is issued when method ends.

What can be the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA provider needs to flush the persistence context before query execution if there is the possibility that query results would not be consistent with the current persistent context state.

You can set [flush mode](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#setFlushMode-javax.persistence.FlushModeType-) to [`COMMIT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/FlushModeType.html#COMMIT) for the desired (or all) sessions. Just keep in mind to manually flush the session if a query depends on the dirty persistence context state. Default flush mode is [`AUTO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/FlushModeType.html#AUTO), meaning that persistence context may be flushed before query execution.

Comment: hmm....that's a very plausible point. Thanks a ton. BTW,how do you know every nitty gritty of JPA behaviour.I keep on reading and experimenting every time, but still every now and then such issues keep cropping up which I find hard to explain. Any good resource?

Comment: You're welcome. There's no a single learning source covering everything. Books, forums, articles, experimenting, deep diving source code...

Comment: You should read the spec https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=338
IMHO this is very clear.
BTW my answer bellow is correct just in case...

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the database isolation level. It's read_commited by default.
Read more about isolation levels here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Read_committed

So to not break this isolation JPA MUST execute all SQL statements in the buffer that all data in the transaction has reached the database.